# What is the connection between the "Ghost in the Shell" (not-)Aphex Twin YouTube and upcoming Feature Film?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Is this YouTube video titled [Aphex Twin - Ghost In The Shell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOi7E8vbj1c) related to the upcoming feature film release [Ghost in the Shell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219827/)? They both involve cyborg police and hackers, so they are similar, but there is also a media franchise with the same name.

<s>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOi7E8vbj1c</s> video has since been deleted but (to the best of my memory) [this is the same or very similar](https://youtu.be/hddCWk5trdo) (age restricted for robot nudity?) and here's the audio (mix of music and dialogue):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming live-action movie [is an adaptation](http://www.theverge.com/2016/4/18/11455160/ghost-in-the-shell-scarlett-johansson-hollywood-casting) of a 1995 anime film, or possibly the 1989 manga it was based on--both were also called [*Ghost in the Shell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell), and the movie is on video [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L6AW2MC). That youtube video you posted is blocked on copyright grounds where I live, but the preview image is a shot from the 1995 movie. According to a reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cyberpunk_Music/comments/37ngi9/ghost_in_the_shell_by_aphex_twin_its_not_by_aphex/), it's not actually by Aphex Twin, it's a remix of a song from the 1995 movie's soundtrack that's been circulating under that mislabeled title for a long time:

> And to clarify the slightly weird title of this post, I first heard this track in the days of [Napster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napster) when it was attributed to Aphex Twin for some reason. Apparently it's a hard-to-find remix of the track 'Puppetmaster' from the original soundtrack, done by the original composer Kenji Kawai.

Comment: Thank you for all of the clarifications! I was a bit confused because it certainly does not sound like Aphex Twin - this makes more sense. If you think there's any adjustments to the question and title in light of the attribution, please make them!

Comment: I've had to update the question as the original YouTube link went dead, I've added two more.